# Delphi and NodeJS - Encrypt array of byte buffer (Rijndael cipher)

Tags: arrays, node.js, sockets, delphi, encryption

I'm creating an application that uses Socket to communicate (server<->client).

The server is made in NodeJS and the client in Delphi.

To encrypt the packets server-side I'm using Rijndael 128-bit ECB. I must be able to encrypt and decrypt on the two sides.

This is a sample code of the server-side NodeJS script:

```
var MCrypt = require('mcrypt').MCrypt;

var desEcb = new MCrypt('rijndael-128', 'ecb');
desEcb.open('1234567890123456', 'abcdefghijklmnop'); // key and IV

var encrypted_buffer = desEcb.encrypt(new Buffer([0x4d,0x79,0x20,0x64,0x61,0x74,0x61]));
console.log(encrypted_buffer);
```

The output buffer is: `4f ce 37 97 7a dc 11 a9 11 75 97 e6 a3 a4 ae 28`

And, in Delphi, this is my code (I'm using [DCPCrypt2](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt/) lib):

```
procedure EncryptBuf;
const
  buf: array[0..6] of byte = ($4d, $79, $20, $64, $61, $74, $61);
var
  Cipher : TDCP_Rijndael;
  Key, IV : string;
  data: TByteArray; //32768 bytes
begin
  // Pad Key, IV and Data with zeros as appropriate
  Key := PadWithZeros('1234567890123456', 16);
  IV := PadWithZeros('abcdefghijklmnop', 16);

  // Create the cipher and initialise according to the key length
  Cipher := TDCP_Rijndael.Create(nil);

  Cipher.Init(Key[1], 128, @IV[1]);    {128, 192, 256}

  Cipher.EncryptECB(buf[0], data[0]);

  form1.memo1.lines.add(BufferToHex(data[0], length(data)));

  // Free the cipher and clear sensitive information
  Cipher.Free;
  FillChar(Key[1],Length(Key),0);
end;
```

However, the output buffer I got is: `06 03 AA D5 51 EB 2B 8C 24 D5 4E BF D3 55 2E AA`

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Node.JS code uses zero block padding (I used [TForge](https://bitbucket.org/sergworks/tforge/overview) library to detect it):

```
program Project14;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, tfTypes, tfBytes, tfCiphers;

procedure Test;
var
  Cipher: TCipher;
  PlainText, EncryptedText, Key, IV: ByteArray;

begin
  Key:= ByteArray.FromText('1234567890123456');
//  IV is not needed in ECB mode
//  IV:=  ByteArray.FromText('abcdefghijklmnop');
  PlainText:= ByteArray.Parse('0x4d,0x79,0x20,0x64,0x61,0x74,0x61', ',');
  Writeln(PlainText.ToHex);

  EncryptedText:= TCipher.AES
//                  .ExpandKey(Key, ECB_ENCRYPT or PADDING_ZERO, IV)
                  .ExpandKey(Key, ECB_ENCRYPT or PADDING_ZERO)
                  .EncryptData(PlainText);
  Writeln(EncryptedText.ToHex);

//  Cipher:= TCipher.AES.ExpandKey(Key, ECB_DECRYPT or PADDING_ZERO, IV);
  Cipher:= TCipher.AES.ExpandKey(Key, ECB_DECRYPT or PADDING_ZERO);
  PlainText:= Cipher.DecryptData(EncryptedText);
  Writeln(PlainText.ToHex);

  readln;
end;

begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Note that zero padding does not allow correct decryption (the decrypted data is also padded with zeroes, as the above code shows).

DCPCrypt does not support padding, so you need to pad your plaintext data yourself. It is easy in case of zero padding - just pad your plaintext `buf` with zeroes to 16 bytes (haven't DCPCrypt installed, can't test).

Comment: Hi @user246408, thanks for the reply. Which version of Delphi and TForge are you using? I use Delphi 7 and I'm getting lots of errors when compiling TForge 075. And, in case of using DCPCrypt, why do I have to pad the buf to 16 bytes? What about if my buf is bigger than 16 bytes?

Comment: TForge does not support Delphi 7 (minimal supported version is Delphi 2009).

Comment: And don't use DCPCrypt, if you can upgrade from Delphi 7.

Comment: Well, I have a license for Delphi XE4 and older versions. I like to use Delphi 7 because the size of the binaries are less than the binaries compiled by newer Delphi versions. Anyway, If I have no choice I will download Delphi 2009 and create a library to use in my Delphi 7 project. Do you know any other crypto library that supports Delphi 7? Thanks

Comment: I would recommend Delphi XE for TForge (with Delphi 2009 you may need to edit package options to install it). Sorry, I don't know what libraries still support D7.

Comment: I just tested your code in Delphi XE4 and it's working perfectly. I will still wait for a solution that works in Delphi 7. If I don't get one, I will be back here in about 2-3 days to mark your answer as a solution. Anyway, I'd like to know why do I have to pad the buf to 16 bytes? And what I have to do if my buf is bigger than 16 bytes?

Comment: You should learn about padding - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Byte_padding . With AES the block size is 16 bytes, so the last block is padded to 16 bytes before encryption. TForge has built-in support for padding, with default padding PKCS#7 (PADDING_PKCS). DCPCrypt does not support padding, and you should pad the last block yourself before encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The NodeJS script uses ECB mode which does not use an iv yet one is provided. Also there is a disconnect between the var name `desEcb` which seems to imply DES encryption yet the algorithm is specified as `rijndael-128` which is essentially AES encryption.

The Delphi code uses ECB mode which does not use an iv yet one is provided.

It is best to supply an encryption key of exactly the correct length (128, 192, 256 bits for AES) because key padding is not specified and different implementation are free to be different.

Generally padding is required and the standard is [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7), not null padding. Note that binary data can not be used with null padding.

Note: Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead of ECB mode use CBC mode with a random iv, just prepend the iv to the encrypted data for use on decryption.

If you want to test your encryption on line use [AES CALCULATOR](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc) by Cryptomathic.